# Running scripts on raspberry pi from the internet

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am running python scripts on the pi using another voice recognition python script at the moment. I now also want to run these scripts from the internet. According to a little bit of research, one way could be setting up a small webserver on the pi such as lighttpd and create a database on it. Then create another small script which periodically checks a value in the database. This value can be modified over the internet. According to the value I will be using the voice recognition script or using the other values in the database to run the python scripts.

My question is, is this method efficient or is there a simpler method to do this? I am fairly competent at python but I am totally new to web servers and databases. However I do not mind to spend time learning how to use them.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is a [Raspberry Pi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) forum here. You might want to check them out.

Comment: @Elias Oh! Thanks! Extremely new to stack exchange.

Answer (score 0):

One route that I personally chose, was the configure the Pi for use as a LAMP (Liniux Apache MySQL Python).  Some great instructions can be found here: http://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Raspberry-Pi-Web-Server

If this is overkill, have you considered using cron jobs to automate your pythons scripts?  You could then set up times at which your two scripts would run, and with a little inter-process communication you have two entities that are aware of each other.  http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml

Comment: Actually I have considered cron. The thing is, I want to switch between the voice recognition script and the commands sent over the net on the fly. So my idea is that I use a master script that keeps checking my database for values which I can update over the net. Then this script runs the voice recognition script or the other python scripts depending on the set of values in the database. Anyway, Thanks for the links!!